# Eigenvalues of Lagrangian/action operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

Is it possible to make a prediction for the eigenvalues of the Lagrangian-/action-operator of a quantum system if I know the ones of the Hamiltonian, the position- and momentum-operator?

Can I use the formula

$$
L = \sum_a \frac{1}{2} ( \dot{q}_a \cdot p_a + p_a\cdot \dot{q}_a )- H
$$

to find the eigenvalues since the operators $H, p, \dot{q}$ do not commute with each other (and so they are not diagonizable with the same basis)? So the eigenvalues of $L$ are not $T-V$. Which orthonormal basis can we choose for the calculation instead?

I know that the Hamilton and Heisenberg equations also hold for this operator version (see Quantum kinematics and dynamics by J. Schwinger). So I can use

$$ \dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$$

or a bit more general in terms of the Heisenberg equations:

$$ \dot{q(t)} = {\frac {i}{\hbar }}[H,q(t)]+\left({\frac {\partial q}{\partial t}}\right)_{H}$$

to reformulate the Lagrangian which then depends only on $q,p$ since $H(q,p)$:

$$ L(q(t),p(t)) = \sum_a \frac{1}{2} [{\frac {i}{\hbar }}[H,q_a(t)] \cdot p_a(t) + p_a(t) \cdot {\frac {i}{\hbar }}[H,q_a(t)]+ ]- H(q(t),p(t))
$$

But I also didn't know (with this Lagrangian) which eigenvectors I have to choose.

Since I'm studying Schwinger's quantum action principle I'm interestend in this eigenvalues because they should be minimized by the condition $\delta \hat{S} = 0$

Comment: Up to now nothing useful. Cause I can't find an orthonormal basis in which $p, H$ are diagonal if $H$ depends on $q$. Am I wrong?

Comment: The thread you mentioned is not useful to me because I'm really interested in the eigenvalues of $L$ or $S$ (according to Schwinger's quantum action principle).

Comment: You know how to write *L* in terms of (Heisenberg) operatrors, explicitly. Do it in your question.

Comment: Added some new informations. What exactly do you mean with "rewriting $L$ in terms of (Heisenberg) operators explicitly"?

Comment: Then I only know that I can diagonalize the operator $L$ but not what the eigenvalues are in general (like some combination of the eigenvalues of $p,q,H$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recast your problem, but, full disclosure, I will not attempt to answer open-ended unstated questions on 
[Schwinger’s action principle](http://www.pnas.org/content/102/22/7783.full), also see [Milton 2005](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08091), or the actual mainstream equivalent formulations of 
Dirac’s seminal [1933 path integral paper](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/Dirac33.pdf)
which Feynman streamlined so magnificently that everyone in the identical question is admonishing you to not even ask.

I will narrowly recast your question to a more systematically answerable one. In the Heisenberg representation, ignoring red-herring explicit time dependent Schr operators for simplicity, 
$$
A(t)=e^{itH/\hbar} A e^{-itH/\hbar}\equiv U A U^\dagger.
$$
Applying this to *q(t)* and *p(t)*, and resolving the commutators for a conventional Hamiltonian 
$p^2/2 + V(q)$  complete your return calculation to the Lagrangian,
$$
L= U (p^2/2 -V(q))U^\dagger  ~.
$$
Now, the key point that everybody is reminding everybody is that, in general, that parenthesis, and so *L* , does *not commute* with *H*, so it is not time-invariant, unlike *H*. So you may not commute the *U* on the left to annihilate its unitary inverse on the right, easily. The expression, in general, is a time-dependent mess that most would sensibly not deign to look at.

But, if you must, look at its spectrum at *t* =0, just the parenthesis. The (real!) eigenvalue spectrum of the expression in the Hermitian operator of the parenthesis, barring freak complications, 
is gotten by finding the spectrum of a bizarre inverted potential in any picture you like, e.g. the Schroedinger picture.

As a formal wisecrack, imagine your original Hamiltonian potential is the inverted oscillator 
[Yuce, Kilic & Coruh  Phys Scr 74 (2006) 114](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/74/1/014/meta), also [available on the arXiV](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703234) , that is $V=-\omega^2 q^2$, so, then  your *L* will be identical to the plain oscillator *H* of sophomore physics!

(Forget about your awful spectrum of *your H*, addressed in the refs provided.)  Conclusion: the spectrum of *this L* is that of the plain oscillator, $\hbar \omega (n+1/2)$, being totally schematic and unashamedly cavalier about boundary conditions.

This is all to dramatize that, the spectral problem of *L*, in principle, is a freak Schroedinger problem that does not, and should not!, get anybody anyplace. (Which is the reason most people recoil from Schwinger’s variational principle and map it to Dirac-Feynman.)

But, to dispel an apparent technical misconception of yours, the (real) spectrum of a Hermitian operator need not reflect simultaneous eigenstates of the component operators involved in the operator. (So, in Sophomore physics, the eigenstates of the oscillator hamiltonian are neither eigenstates of *p* nor *q*, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for clearifying the question. It was clear to me that the spectrum of an operator is in general not the same as a combination of the underlaying operator-eigenvalues (the question was more like: since this with the orthonormal basis for all underlaying operators doesn't work is there any other possibility to calculate the spectrum simple with the information of the quantum system. But I agree my question was bad formulated. I had some hope that I can calculate the spectrum of $L=T-V$ in an easy way but as you wrote this is in general not possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no operator corresponding to $\dot{q}$  so that the question seems meaningless to me.

Or better, *what is the meaning of the* **operator** *$\dot{q}$ in terms of operators $p$ and $q$?*

In classical  mechanics, when dealing with the variational Hamiltonian principle,  that  $\dot{q}$ is the derivative of $q$ along a generic  curve and **not** the the effective motion solution of Hamilton equations, which is found stationarizing the action. Passing to the quantum formulation there is no generic *curve of operators* $q=q(t)$ where the derivative can be computed. It cannot  be the Heisenberg evolution of $q$,  since we do not know that evolution at this stage of computations.

Perhaps the question may make sense, but not in this form. Everything should be written using *only* operators $p$ and $q$.

Comment: But the Hamilton equation still hold (Schwinger showed thi in his textbook: Quantum kinematics and dynamics). So we can set $\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$. By doing so we expressed $\dot{q}$ in terms of $q,p$.